# Full screen frame issue

Tags: java, swing, jframe, fullscreen

I have this code, which basically initializes a new JFrame and sets it full screen

```
public class FullScreenFrameTest extends JFrame {

    public FullScreenFrameTest() {
        super();
        initFrame();
        setVisible(true);

        //full screen
        GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice device = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        device.setFullScreenWindow(this);
        //end full screen
    }

    public void initFrame() {
        Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setLocation(0, 0); //tried removing this, still doesn't work
        setSize(screen.width, screen.height);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        new FullScreenFrameTest();
    }
}
```

The problem is that it sometimes it does work and sometimes it doesn't, especially with Ubuntu: sometimes i see it full screen, sometimes the two bars are shown. What am i missing?

**UPDATE**

There is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: [`invokeLater()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)?

Comment: 1) Java GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.  2) See also [`Frame.setExtendedState(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState%28int%29).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes, missed that, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to build your GUI on the event dispatch thread with [`invokeLater()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Update: Here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that seems to work consistently.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class FullScreenFrameTest extends JFrame {

    public FullScreenFrameTest() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setUndecorated(true);
        add(new JLabel("Test", JLabel.CENTER));
        GraphicsEnvironment env =
            GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice device = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        device.setFullScreenWindow(this);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new FullScreenFrameTest();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Even with `setExtendedState()`?

Comment: Yes, also with `setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)`

Comment: `FUllScreenFrameTest` vs. `FullScreenFrameTest`? `TantaBellaRoba` not included in `invokeLater()`?

Comment: Also make `setVisible` last.

Comment: Also your last update doesn't work. But, if i place `setVisible(true)` **before** `GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();` it works the first time, if i close the application and reopen it, it doesn't work

Comment: Work's for me on Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS, Java 1.6.0_27.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
setLocation(0, 0); //tried removing this, still doesn't work
setSize(screen.width, screen.height);
```

To

```
setExtendedState(java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

And call `FullScreenFrameTest()` constructor within `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`.

**UPDATE**

This might be due to the bug in java run time environment. Here is the bug reported https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7057287
To know more about this issue look at [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8838884/1981279).

**UPDATE**
As last tryI would suggest you to use `JFrame#setAlwaysOnTop(true)`

Comment: Have you tried my update? You are referring to that bar which is shown in right hand side of screen?

Comment: THe right one and also the top one, i want a full screen undecorated window, so none of the bars should be visible while my application is in fullscreen mode

Comment: `GraphicsDevice#isFullScreenSupported()` is returning true in your application?

Comment: I'm using jdk1.7u25, by the way i'm not using KDE, i'm using Unity

Comment: Have you seen the link to stackoverflow that i sent you? It explained the reason..And in some answer it is also mentioned that it is not not working for unity also.