# Fullscreen GUI that work on all OS

Tags: java, swing, awt, fullscreen

I am very new in Java. I want to use a code for full screen form. I want that is working in all OS. I found a code that used AWT, but AWT does not work in Linux.

I need a code that doesn't use AWT.

Comment: If you don,t want to use AWT then you can use Swing(preferred) or JavaFX.Simple googling can help you learn

Comment: put here what you have tried, so that we can have a better understanding of your question....

Comment: *"i found a code that used awt, awt don't work in linux"*  Of course it does, but use Swing.

Comment: Your Question depends on the GUI Toolkit, or code to produce a graphical user interface. If AWT doesn't work for you, pick another one! There is for example SWING and SWT .

Comment: Try the complete Swing examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7457102/230513) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17340322/230513).

Answer (score 1):

Although statement "AWT does not work in Linux" sounds very strange I have to mention that you indeed need more than AWT to create full screen application in java. Take a look on the tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html

that explains a lot of nice techniques including full screen windows. Search for `full-screen` (with dash) in this article.